# Indexing array from second element for all elements

Tags: python, numpy, slice

I think it must be easy, but I cannot google it. Suppose I have array of numbers 1, 2, 3, 4.

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
```

How to index array if I want sequence 2, 3, 4, 1?? 
I know that for sequence 2, 3, 4 I can choose e.g.:

```
print(a[1::1])
```

Answer (score 1):

If you want to rotate the list, you can use a [deque](https://docs.python.org/3.8/library/collections.html#deque-objects) instead of a numpy array. This data structure is designed for this kind of operation and directly provides a rotate function.

```py
>>> from collections import deque
>>> a = deque([1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> a.rotate(-1)
>>> a
deque([2, 3, 4, 1])
```

---

If you want to use Numpy, you can check out the `roll` function.

```py
>>> import numpy as np
>>> a = np.array([1,2,3,4])
>>> np.roll(a, -1)
array([2, 3, 4, 1])
```

Answer (score 0):

One possible way is to define index set (a list).

```
index_set = [1, 2, 3, 0]
print(a[index_set])
```